# How do I force microk8s kubectl to generate a token for my dashboard?

Tags: kubernetes, microk8s

I'm trying to get the token for the kubernetes dashboard. It seems none was generated. How do I force it to generate one? Here is what I did:

I've installed Ubuntu 20.04 on a hyperV VM on my local laptop. I used the ubuntu installer to install the microk8s snap.
I then installed dashboard among other things with this command:

```
microk8s enable dns dashboard storage
```

With a separate terminal I started a proxy:

```
microk8s kubectl port-forward -n kube-system service/kubernetes-dashboard 10443:443 --address 0.0.0.0
```

which of course asks for a token.
When trying to export the token with:

```
token=$(microk8s kubectl -n kube-system get secret | grep default-token | cut -d " " -f1)
microk8s kubectl -n kube-system describe secret $token
```

the resulting output shows no token:

```
Name:         kubernetes-dashboard-certs
Namespace:    kube-system
Labels:       k8s-app=kubernetes-dashboard
Annotations:  <none>

Type:  Opaque

Data
====


Name:         kubernetes-dashboard-csrf
Namespace:    kube-system
Labels:       k8s-app=kubernetes-dashboard
Annotations:  <none>

Type:  Opaque

Data
====
csrf:  256 bytes


Name:         kubernetes-dashboard-key-holder
Namespace:    kube-system
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  <none>

Type:  Opaque

Data
====
priv:  1675 bytes
pub:   459 bytes
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're probably already on version 1.24 or higher. So the command is much simpler:

`microk8s kubectl create token default`

will throw a token to `stdout` which you can use for the dashboard.

Answer (score 1):

If the default expiration date for the token bothers you e.g. is too short you may set an extended period for the token (example: 10 years in minutes)

```
   microk8s kubectl -n kubernetes-dashboard create token simple-user --duration 525600m
```

I use this in an online demo to allow limited access for demo users.
https://dashboard.homekube.org
(basic auth with demo/demo)